# Defining administrator messages from MobileFirst Operations Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

Hi I am Defining administrator messages from MobileFirst Operations Console for access disabled in mobilefirst 8.0.

Is there any way to change header of the message alert box like we can change message? Now its "Application Disabled". I want to change this.

Comment: Cordova or Native?

Comment: @IdanAdar hybrid cordova application

Answer (score 0):

See this documentation topic: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/translation/#cordova-applications

You should be able to find the corresponding variable for the header of the dialog in the `messages.json` file. The file is available after the application has been built.

- Android: [Cordova-project]\platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-mfp\worklight\messages
- iOS, Windows: [Cordova-project]\platforms[ios or windows]\www\plugins\cordova-plugin-mfp\worklight\messages

The variable to look for is this:

```
"applicationDenied" : "Application Disabled",
```

You will then need to override it in your applicative code.
For example:

```
WL.ClienMessages.applicationDenied = "Sorry!";
```

Should work...

Comment: I can not modify directly in messages.json file?

Comment: Per the documentation you shouldn't, as it states otherwise. Do whatever you feel is right for your app.

Comment: but in my current project messages.json I dont have any variable having value "Application Disabled". So where its comes from?

Comment: This file is inside the MobileFirst Cordova SDK/plug-in. This file is generated only once you build the Cordova project and is available in the generated project... look at the path I've mentioned in the answer.